# Binominal problem (I think) to calculate strategy for a mobile game - cost of money in a game of ensuring a certain number of events

Tags: probability

There is a mobile game where I am trying to calculate the correct strategy that depends on a series of randomized events.

The game is a battle game where you place troops on a field.  When you want to place a troop, you hit a button and one of five random troops will be placed.  For the sake of this question, the troops are a knight, archer, goblin, wizard, and gnome.  Thus, you have a 20% chance of getting one of those particular cards when you push the button.

To push the button and put a troop on the field costs 100 dollars for the first troop, but increases by 10 dollars for each subsequent troop.  Thus the first troop the player puts on the field costs 100 dollars, the second costs 110 dollars, etc.

The question is what is the probability I get x knights on the field if I push the button y times (and how much will it cost).  Put another way, if I want to be, say, 75% sure that I get 3 knights, how many times should I push the button and pay for a troop and how much will it cost?  This is my basic question (and I'd like to know how to calculate it if I want 5 knights, or 7 knights).

If you want to go down the rabbit hole further with me (and I'd be very happy just for an answer for the above) - another rule of the game is if you have the same troop on the field, you can combine it with another troop of the same kind, in which case those two troops will disappear and it will produce one other random card.  Thus, for example, if your first five troops on the field are knight, archer, archer, goblin, goblin; you can combine the two archers and you will get one new random card (say a knight), and you can combine the two goblins and get one new random card (say a goblin).  So you would then have knight, knight, goblin.  It does not cost money to combine cards, but combining them can increase the chance you get a knight because it gives you another free card.

With this complication, what is the probability that I will get 3 knights on the field after pushing the button 15 times (creating 15 troops), and then combining any non-knight troops that match?  Or put another way, if I want to be 75% confident that I will get 3 knights, how many times should I push the button (taking into account I can combine non-knight troops to get new cards)?  Again, is there a formula that could calculate this so I can see what my probability is if I push the button 20 times or another amount?

Hopefully that's clear.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: My question for you: What Game?

Comment: The game is Rush Royale

Answer (score 1):

I will only focus on the first question.

As you only care about knights, the question is simply:

> each time you push a button, you get a knight with probability $p = 20\%$; what is the probability of getting at least $k$ knights after pressing $n$ times the button?

This is then a very standard exercise in probability. The answer is $P(n, k) = \sum_{i = k}^n \binom n i p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}$.

This formula answers your questions. For example, if you want to get $3$ knights with probability at least $75\%$, then you need to choose $n$ such that $P(n, 3) \geq 75\%$. We make the following table:

```
n  P(n, k)
3  0.008000000000000
4  0.027200000000000
5  0.057920000000000
6  0.098880000000000
7  0.148032000000000
8  0.203082240000000
9  0.261802496000000
10 0.322200473600000
11 0.382598451200000
12 0.441654251520000
13 0.498347819827200
14 0.551949011681281
15 0.601976790745089
16 0.648156279111681
17 0.690377525618279
18 0.728658122450928
19 0.763110659600313
20 0.793915281051527
```

which shows that you should choose $n = 19$.

As to the total cost, it is simply a function of $n$, namely $100 \times n + 10 \times n(n - 1)/2 = 5n^2 + 95n$. Thus for $n = 19$ the cost is $3610$.

---

Note that another more useful information is the **expected cost** until $3$ knights occur. This is another topic, though.

Comment: Thanks - that is helpful.  Since you invited the question, what about expected cost?